# My codes are not doing get,set,post so what is my codes error how can i fix it?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

these are my .ts codes i write these becasue i want to get product details and delete

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms"
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/services/product.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/services/local-storage.service';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-delete',
  templateUrl: './product-delete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-delete.component.css']
})
export class ProductDeleteComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  dataLoaded = false;
  deleteProductForm:FormGroup;
  product :Product 
  productId :number;
 


  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, 
    private productService:ProductService
    , private toastrService:ToastrService
    ,private router:Router,
    private localStorageService:LocalStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
     
    
   this.createdeleteProductForm();
  }
 

  createdeleteProductForm(){
    this.deleteProductForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    
      productId:["", Validators.required],
     
    })
 }

 



  getbyid() {
    Number(localStorage)
    Number(this.productService)
 
      this.productService.getbyid(Number(localStorage.getItem("productId"))).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.products = response.data;
          this.dataLoaded = true;
 
  
          this.deleteProductForm.setValue({
            productId: this.product,
    categoryId: this.product.categoryId,
    productName: this.product.productName,
    unitPrice: this.product.unitPrice
    
   
  
             
             
            
          });
        },
        (responseError) => {
          this.toastrService.error(responseError.error);
        }
      )
  }



  deleteProduct() {
    if (this.deleteProductForm.valid) {
      let productModel = Object.assign({}, this.deleteProductForm.value);

      productModel.productId=parseInt(productModel.productId);

      this.productService.delete(productModel).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.toastrService.success('Lütfen tekrar giriş yapınız');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
         
        },
        (responseError) => {
          this.toastrService.error(responseError.error);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.toastrService.error('Bir hata oluştu.');
   
    }
  }


}
```

these are my html codes  i trying to do when user sign in a productId after that click the button delete the product in that ıd

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"><h5 class="title">Ürün Sil</h5></div>
        <div class="card-body">
   
          <form [formGroup]="deleteProductForm">
          
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="productId">ÜrünId'si</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" 
                id="productId" 
                formControlName="productId" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="productId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer" style="background-color: rgb(4, 62, 255)">
              <button
                class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success float-end"
                (click)="deleteProduct()"
              >
     Sils
              </button>
            </div>
```

and these are my service

```
  delete(product:Product):Observable<ResponseModel>{
    let newPath = this.apiUrl + 'products/delete';
    return this.httpClient.post<ResponseModel>(newPath, product );
  }

 getbyid(productId:number) : Observable<ListResponseModel<Product>> {
  let newPath = this.apiUrl + 'products/getbyid?productId=' + productId;
  return this.httpClient.get<ListResponseModel<Product>>(newPath);
}
```

what i'm going for is that when the user goes on a productId click the button, I want to delete the data including the Id first, but what's the null time on main at the moment?

note:Value cannot be null. says back-end
in html POST https://localhost:44314/api/products/delete
[HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 9591ms gives this error

Comment: Please don't tag VS or VS Code unless the issue is specific to either of these - which I don't think it is. You would be better off tagging Angular

Comment: what is this large number of empty lines

Comment: its just nothing i just blank that beacuse i thinking add things

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you checked the value of `product` in the call of `delete` ?

Also, maybe it's the httpClient.delete you need since it's the best way to delete an object to the back end. I suggest this:

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request

Comment: yes i checkd but product values are not coming beacause this is delete command it job is delete   and  i look at angular i know it but not want do  like this

Comment: Try adding console.log('product: ' + JSON.stringify(product)) after the line let newPath = this.apiUrl + 'products/delete'; What does it show in the console ?

Comment: well its just seeing what i entered value like this product: {"productId":2}